# Datasource iMacro using %userprofile%

Tags: html, imacros

I'm making a script on iMacro, but i don't want put my username, so i'm trying using `%userprofile%` `%username%` `%homepath%`, etc.

But when i run, it recognize the folder, and the location of the file `dates.csv`, but it says that the file was not found, and then shows a massage and the program closes.

Follow bellow the iMacro code using `!DATASOURCE`

```
SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE C:\Users\%username%\Arquivos<SP>Extratos<SP>Bancos\WAS\
SET !DATASOURCE dates.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```

Follow the error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrCa.png)

How can i fix it?

Comment: If the FOLDER_DATASOURCE value contains a SPACE character, perhaps it needs to be quoted. Are you sure it can use a directory containing a SPACE character?

Comment: Yes, in the place of the space, we have to put `<SP>`

Comment: I tried but i can't i need 1500 points for add imacro tag

Comment: See the comment at https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8307 The iMacros forum might be a more direct place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE 
C:\Users\%username%\Arquivos<SP>Extratos<SP>Bancos\WAS\dates.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```