# Sort lines of a .txt file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a `.txt` like that below:

```
MasterCard 
R$ 66,12 

Hipercard 
R$ 7.501,98 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 7.742,46 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 5.846,14 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 4.210,65 

Visa
R$ 4.210,65 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 2.892,20 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

Visa
R$ 4.210,65

Hipercard 
R$ 1.944,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 584,04 

Visa
R$ 4.210,65
```

I need a `.bat` file (could be in PowerShell) that organize the lines by the descrption and value, like below:

```
-----------------
MasterCard 
R$ 66,12 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

MasterCard 
R$ 48,19 

----------------      
Hipercard 
R$ 7.501,98 

Hipercard 
R$ 7.742,46 

Hipercard 
R$ 5.846,14 

Hipercard 
R$ 4.210,65

Hipercard 
R$ 2.892,20 

Hipercard 
R$ 1.944,19 

Hipercard 
R$ 584,04 

--------------        
Visa
R$ 4.210,65 

Visa
R$ 4.210,65

Visa
R$ 4.210,65
```

It's possibile do it with a `.bat` file? I'm stuck in how to start.
I was trying using a simple command: `sort test.txt /o testout.txt`

But it's not working.

---

I have another idea. Running this command i can put all lines in the same line:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("frt01.txt") do (echo(%%a)>>test.txt
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("test.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i ">>"test2.txt"
del test.txt /S /Q /
```

So now, the description and values are all in only one line:

```
MasterCard  R$ 66,12  Hipercard  R$ 7.501,98  MasterCard  R$ 48,19  Hipercard  R$ 7.742,46  MasterCard  R$ 48,19  Hipercard  R$ 5.846,14  MasterCard  R$ 48,19  Hipercard  R$ 4.210,65  MasterCard  R$ 48,19  Hipercard  R$ 2.892,20  MasterCard  R$ 48,19  Hipercard  R$ 1.944,19  Hipercard  R$ 584,04
```

How can i do for it be like bellow? (Type a 'enter' after each value)

```
MasterCard  R$ 66,12  
Hipercard  R$ 7.501,98  
MasterCard  R$ 48,19  
Hipercard  R$ 7.742,46  
MasterCard  R$ 48,19  
Hipercard  R$ 5.846,14  
MasterCard  R$ 48,19  
Hipercard  R$ 4.210,65  
MasterCard  R$ 48,19  
Hipercard  R$ 2.892,20  
MasterCard  R$ 48,19  
Hipercard  R$ 1.944,19  
Hipercard  R$ 584,04
```

Because then i can sort with this command: `sort test2.txt /o output.txt`

I guess doing by this way is easier.

---

@michael_heath This is what i was talking:

```
Hipercard   R$    584,04
Hipercard   R$  1.944,19
Hipercard   R$  2.892,20
Hipercard   R$  4.210,65
Hipercard   R$  5.846,14
Hipercard   R$  7.501,98
Hipercard   R$  7.742,46
------------------------
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     66,12
------------------------
Visa        R$     48,19
Visa        R$     48,19
Visa        R$     48,19
------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All batch-file code**

**Option 1**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (frt01.txt) do (
        if not "%%~A" == "R$" (
            set "card=%%~A          "
            set "card=!card:~,11!"
        ) else (
            set "value=          %%~B"
            set "value=!value:~-9!"
            echo !card! %%~A !value!
        )
    )
) > unsorted.txt

sort unsorted.txt /o output.txt

rem  Optional code below to insert ------- between rows after sort.

set "last_card="
(
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (output.txt) do (
        for /f %%B in ("%%~A") do set "card=%%~B"
        if defined last_card if not "!card!" == "!last_card!" (
            echo ------------------------
        )
        echo %%A
        set "last_card=!card!"
    )
    echo ------------------------
) > tmp.txt

move /y tmp.txt output.txt
```

This is the delayed expansion concept. Fixed spacing is
used so `sort` can order better with different lengths
of the cards and of the currency values.

- `for /?` for token descriptions etc.
- `set /?` for substitution syntax used i.e. `set "card=!card:~,11!"`.

---

**Option 2**

```
@(
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (frt01.txt) do (
        if not "%%~A" == "R$" (
            set "card=%%~A          "
            call set "card=%%card:~,11%%"
        ) else (
            set "value=          %%~B"
            call set "value=%%value:~-9%%"
            call echo "%%card%%" "%%A" "%%value%%"
        )
    )
) | sort /o output.txt
```

This is a unusual concept. Like previous code, uses fixed
spacing. It uses no temporary file as it pipes direct to
`sort`.

Uses `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` even though no `!`
are used. Delayed variables would not expand. Without,
delayed expansion, the `call set` and `call echo` would
not work.

Works on Win7 though perhaps it's strange behavior may
make the other code a better option.

---

**Option 3**

```
@echo off
setlocal

if not "%~1" == "" (
    if "%~1" == "/?" goto :help
    for %%A in (%*) do call :read "%%~A"
    exit /b
)

rem If no arguments, do this optional task instead.
> "%~dp0unsorted.txt" call :read "frt01.txt"
sort "%~dp0unsorted.txt" /o "%~dp0output.txt"
del "%~dp0unsorted.txt"

exit /b

:read
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%A in ("%~1") do (
    if not "%%~A" == "R$" (
        set "card=%%~A          "
        set "card=!card:~,11!"
    ) else (
        set "value=          %%~B"
        set "value=!value:~-9!"
        echo !card! %%~A !value!
    )
)
exit /b

:help
echo Prints Hipercard, MasterCard... vertical list as 3 horizontal fixed columns.
echo If multiple files are passed as arguments, they will be printed in sequence.
echo.
echo Syntax: %~nx0 file [file [file]]
echo.
echo Examples:
echo   %~nx0 "test 1.txt"
echo   %~nx0 test1.txt test2.text ^| sort /o output.txt
exit /b
```

This is a standalone script or run code below the `rem`
*remark* line. You could remove the optional code and place
the script in PATH so you can run it from a console
anywhere.

If the script is named cardsorter.cmd, then you could i.e.

```
cardsorter frt01.txt | sort /o output.txt
```

at a command prompt.

---

**Output Of All Options**

```
Hipercard   R$    584,04
Hipercard   R$  1.944,19
Hipercard   R$  2.892,20
Hipercard   R$  4.210,65
Hipercard   R$  5.846,14
Hipercard   R$  7.501,98
Hipercard   R$  7.742,46
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     48,19
MasterCard  R$     66,12
Visa        R$  4.210,65
Visa        R$  4.210,65
Visa        R$  4.210,65
```

---

**Note**

Option 1 inserts `--------------` to separate card types.

Comment: Ok, nice! The option 1 wroked very weill. But if i want separete the cards with a line between then? `--------------------`

Comment: For option 3. Insert `echo.` after the line `echo !card! %%~A !value!`. `echo.` prints an empty line. Do similar to other options after the echo line.

Comment: Ok, did it, but i didn't explain very well. i Just wanted a line `---------` only at the end of each type of card, to separete then. And there's another problem. When i sort it, all the lines go to the top.

Comment: Needs to be done after `sort`. Updated *Option 1* using a `for` loop to read `output.txt` and insert `--------` between rows and then move the written file `tmp.txt` over `output.txt`.

Comment: Almost! Sorry if i'm not explaining very well, my english is not so good. Please check out my last edit!

Comment: Updated to match your question edit. Sorry if my interpretation is not good enough. Your english is reasonably good. I sometimes misunderstand what people say.

Comment: Good! Perfect. Can you please see if you can answer my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784742/datasource-imacro-using-userprofile

Answer (score 5):

Before you can sort the data, you'll need to parse it. You can use the [`ConvertFrom-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1) with a template to do this:

```
$Template = @'
{CardProvider*:MasterCard}
R$ {Amount:66,12}

{CardProvider*:Hipercard}
R$ {Amount:7.501,98}

{CardProvider*:Visa}
R$ {Amount:4.210,65}

'@

$Transactions = Get-Content path\to\file.txt |ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $Template
```

The `$Transactions` variable will now contain an array of objects with a `CardProvider` and an `Amount` property each. To sort by provider and then by amount we can do something like:

```
# Define output file name
$OutputFile = 'output.txt'
# Group by card type first
$Transactions |Group-Object CardProvider |ForEach-Object {
    # Write seperator to output file:
    '----------------' |Add-Content -Path $OutputFile 
    # Now we sort each group of cards by descending amount
    $_.Group |Sort-Object {$_.Amount -replace '\.' -replace ',','.' -as [decimal]} -Descending |ForEach-Object {
        # Finally write the contents to file again
        $_.CardProvider,"R$ $($_.Amount)","" |Add-Content -Path $OutputFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but, the values will always changes, i forgot to say it. The card names will be always the same, but the value bellow it, will always change

Comment: @Karen `ConvertFrom-String` is likely to still be able to infer the pattern described in the template string - have you tried testing the code I provided? Added another sample for the `Visa` card type

Comment: When i run, it fails saiyng the command 'ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent' are written incorrectly, Can you please check it and put all in one line if possibile?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? `ConvertFrom-String` was introduced in Windows PowerShell 5.0

Comment: I have 2.0 version, i use Windows 7.

Comment: If you can't upgrade to Windows 10, I'd suggest at least installing PowerShell version 5.1 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Comment: Just installed 5.1 version, but now says that System.String[] has no parameters.

Comment: My bad, forget the `$Template` variable after `ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent`

Comment: It's not working well, but i had other idea, can you check my last edit please?

Comment: Nice idea +1, but `ConvertFrom-String` results are a bit disappointing, visa gets pure amount but the other cards have R$ included in amount here. Just discovered **this happens because Mastercard/Hipercard have a trailing space** in above source.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file solution.  To stack the lines together you just use a variable to hold the previous line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "line1="
(FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (input.txt) DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED line1 (
        set "line1=%%G
    ) else (
        echo !line1! %%G
        set "line1="
    )
))>temp.txt
sort temp.txt>output.txt
```

Comment: Nothing happened, the `temp.txt` and `output.txt` was empty.

Comment: @Karen, did you change "input.txt" to what your input file name is?

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help!
Maybe you can answer my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784742/datasource-imacro-using-userprofile

Answer (score 1):

The following code parses the input file into an array of transaction objects, sorts them, then outputs the sorted array. Not that the amounts were sorted as a right-justified string.

```
$unsortedtransactions = @()

Get-Content .\in.txt -ReadCount 3 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Matches = $null
        "$_" -match '([^\s]*)\s*(\S*)\s*(.*)$(.*)$' | Out-Null
        $thisrecord = [PSCustomObject] @{ Card = $Matches[1]
            Currency = $Matches[2]
            Amount = $("{0,15}" -f @($Matches[3].Trim()))
        }
        $unsortedtransactions += $thisrecord
    }

$sortedtransactions = $unsortedtransactions | Sort-Object -Property Card, Currency, Amount

foreach ($t in $sortedtransactions) {
    $("{0}`r`n{1} {2}`r`n" -f @($t.Card, $t.Currency, $t.Amount.Trim())) |
        Out-File -FilePath st.txt -Encoding ascii -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Maybe you can answer my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784742/datasource-imacro-using-userprofile